# （花よりもなほ) What does もなほ mean here?

Tags: meaning, kana-usage

I would like to know what もなほ here means and what it exactly did to the phrase?
I came across it twice and stuck with it, because I don't actually know if it's verb or noun or even adverb.

The other phrase was like this:

> 闇もなほ、

Comment: 闇もなほ is a quote from 枕草子 ([The Pillow Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pillow_Book)) chapter 1, written circa 990 A.D.. http://manapedia.jp/text/2214

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first phrase 花よりもなほ can be split into 3 words: 花-よりも-なほ. Its meaning is "more ... than flowers."

なほ seems to be an old representation of the word that is written "なお" today (which is an adverb). なお is for emphasis in this phrase. なお can typically be used to emphasize comparisons.

In the second phrase 闇もなほ, なほ seems to be also an emphasis. Its meanings is like either "Darkness is also ..." or "Darkness is more ...", depending on context. In the latter case なほ derives a slight feeling of comparison by itself.

Comment: 闇もなお never means "darkness is **more**...", only ～よりもなお and ～はなお make the next word into comparative.